# How to force RESTEasy output number as string in json?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson, resteasy

I want to put a quote "" in the following json from RESTEasy (with Jackson).

```
{
    "isReachable": false,
    "timestamp": 1353449973347
}

{
    "isReachable": "false",
    "timestamp": "1353449973347"
}
```

The reason why I do that is because I am using GWT, and gwt cannot convert timestamp into long datatype. Do you know how to RESTEasy to output value as string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the timestamp property in your pojo that you are serializing with the `@JsonSerialize` annotation and instruct Jackson to use a string serializer.

```
public class YourPojo
{
     private boolean isReachable = false;

     @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
     private Long timestamp;

     //Getters and Setters omitted for brevity
}
```